# When was the Defiant engine room set last seen/torn down?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, behind-the-scenes

The set for the engine room of the DS9 USS Defiant was built [at the end of season 3 as a permanent set](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Defiant_class#Interior). In later seasons the engine room was seen increasingly less, and I wonder when it was last seen / when the set was torn down.

I found [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Paramount_Stage_18#1992-1999) that '*in later years*' the set was '*torn down to make room for a Klingon starship interior and generic Cardassian setting*.'
I also found [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Defiant_class#Main_engineering) that

> At the end of DS9 Season 5, the Defiant-class engineering set was
> deemed to be taking up much-wanted room in the swing set area of the
> Paramount sound stages used by Star Trek: Deep Space Nine. This
> resulted in the set for an overhead flying rig – originally built and
> used for Season 2 installment "Melora" – to be removed from that
> stage.

I'm not sure if the latter quote means that the engine room set was removed, or that just the overhead flying rig was removed. The engine room appears in season 6 episode 14 '[One Little Ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/One_Little_Ship_(episode))', so that seems to indicate that the quote above was just about the overhead flying rig. Or did they rebuild the set just for that season 6 episode? (Note: I haven't watched DS9 s7 yet)

Anyway, my question: when was the Defiant engine room set last seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sound of Her Voice (Season 6 - Episode 25) https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sound_of_Her_Voice_(episode)

Without watching the episode again I believe the final time is a scene in Engineering where O'Brien and Kasidy are in Engineering. O'Brien is working on the com line and he's chatting with Kasidy about the Defiant having civilians aboard then the crashed Captain on the other end of the com link is suddenly able to hear them chatting

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed seem to be the last time we see it!